# PRISM + MEF -- Import & ImportMany

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mef

**FooService.cs**:

```
public interface IFooService
{
    int Foo();
}

[Export("Foo1", typeof(IFooService))]
public class Foo1 : IFooService
{
    public int Foo() { return 1; }
}


[Export("Foo2", typeof(IFooService))]
public class Foo2 : IFooService
{
    public int Foo() { return 2; }
}
```

**FooViewModel.cs**:

```
public class FooViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IFooService))]
    public IEnumerable<IFooService> FooServices { get; private set; }

    [Import("Foo1")]
    public IFooService FirstFoo { get; private set; }
}
```

---

The single import works because I have a named contract, however the multi import doesn't. If I change the Export attributes and remove the named contract, the multi import works, but the single import doesn't. How can I get both to work at the same time?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with prism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put multiple export attributes on your classes:

```
[Export(typeof(IFooService))]
[Export("Foo1", typeof(IFooService))]
public class Foo1 : IFooService
{
    public int Foo() { return 1; }
}

[Export(typeof(IFooService))]
[Export("Foo2", typeof(IFooService))]
public class Foo2 : IFooService
{
    public int Foo() { return 2; }
}
```