# How to import classes as interfaces using Import / ImportMany in Prism?

Tags: prism

I'm trying to import classes of a certain interface type. I already looked for help (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171862/prism-mef-import-importmany)), but I can't seem to get it working.

First, I tried the following:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
   ...
}

[Export(typeof(ISomeInterface))]
public class SomeImplementation: ISomeInterface
{
    ...
}

[ImportingConstructor]
public ScannerMainViewModel([ImportMany(typeof(ISomeInterface))] IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> someImplementations)
{
    ...
}
```

But someImplementations is null.

Then I removed the ImportMany from the constructor and used it on the field

```
[ImportMany(typeof(ISomeInterface))]
private IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> someImplementations;
```

with the same result.

I then removed the ImportMany completely and only imported my one class this way:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public ScannerMainViewModel(ISomeInterface someImplementation)
{
    ...
}
```

This lead to the folling error:

```
An exception has occurred while trying to add a view to region 'MainRegion'. 
- The most likely causing exception was was: 'System.InvalidOperationException: No public constructor is available for type Common.Interfaces.IAccountScanner. ---> Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException: Eine Ausnahme vom Typ "Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException" wurde ausgelöst.
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried to use names for contracts, but that didn't work too.

Comment: Please keep in mind that MEF is no longer supported with Prism and you should be migrating your code away from it!

Comment: @DanSiegel Thanks for your answer. I tried to find out what I need to do, but I couldn't find out what I need to change. I'm used to using an old version of Prism, but I wanted to use the current version this time.